# How to rephrase this sentence with two relative pronouns and still sound natural?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

I just asked a [related question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/36091/how-to-interpret-two-consecutive-wass), and in German, it is not entirely clear what two consecutive relative pronouns "was" each qualify.

> {German}: Es gibt ***nichts***, ***was*** er sagen könnte, ***was*** die Tatsache ändern oder auch nur rechtfertigen würde.

---

In English, on the other hand, two relative pronouns do not seem to give rise to ambiguity, especially since the first "that" can be omitted.

> {English}: There's ***nothing*** (***that***) he could say ***that*** would change or justify the fact.

---

Then I wondered how I would express the same idea in French, and the following construction came to mind first. I notice I kind of *finessed* the issue of a relative pronoun pile-up by not using the second one.

> {French}: ***Rien*** de ce ***qu***’il dirait ne pourrait changer ou justifier ce qui a été fait.

---

But in spontaneous speech, you cannot always start a sentence *ideally* and yet might try to construct the rest of the sentence somehow with what you have started.

So what if you start off with "Il n'y a rien ..." instead and need to incorporate two relative pronouns somehow, just as is the case with the German and English sentences?

This might prove to be a more complex structure than the one I suggested above, but how would you go about it without causing ambiguity?

> Il n'y a ***rien*** ... {with two relative pronouns}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two would work:

- Il n'y a rien qu'il pourrait dire pour changer ou justifier ce qui a été fait.
- Il n'y a rien qu'il pourrait dire qui changerait ou justifierait ce qui a été fait.

Comment: Merci! Regarding your second suggestion, this is exactly what I was pondering on. The first "que" obviously refers to "rien", but I wonder if the second one leaves some ambiguity as to what it qualifies? I assume it qualifies the entire "rien qu'il pourrait dire" rather than "rien"?

Comment: It is absolutely unambiguous. ***Qui*** is put in place of everything and anything that he could say (including any utter non-sense gibberish that he could come up with), and ***rien*** specifies that none of all these could ever work to change or justify what has been done.